# How to display all the workbooks in excel in different instances?

Tags: vba

I am trying to get the names of all workbooks that are currently open. I currently have

```
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook 'wb where macro is
    wb1_name = wb1.Name
    For Each WB In Application.Workbooks
    wb2_name = WB.Name
        If wb2_name <> wb1_name Then
        WB.Activate
        Range("H1").Value = "hello"

        End If
    Next WB

    End Sub
```

It's not able to pick up the other workbook that is open in the loop. It only loops through once, which is the comparing the current workbook to itself, thus doing nothing. This is probably because I had some code that retrieves data from a software, download it and open that excel file. I suspect this file is another instance of Excel when it is downloaded and opened since I clearly see it on my screen.

Comment: are you confusing Worksheet with Workbook ??

Comment: Different instances don't talk to each others, at least not the "normal" way (not in any way that is accessible to mere mortals anyway). `Application` refers to the instance currently running your code. The two instances have process boundaries to cross in order to "talk" to each other. No small task you're asking here. Or is the downloaded workbook simply open in "protected mode" in the same instance?

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: I mean Workbook. I am navigating between two excel workbook. Initially, it is the workbook that contains the code only. The code opens other workbook where the calculation and manipulation of data occurs. I suspect that when the new workbook is opened, it is in a different instance of excel since when I loop through workbooks, it only picks up the workbook that the macro is in and not the one it opened. Version is Excel 2010

Comment: If the code is opening the other workbook, then that other workbook is in the same instance.

Comment: Why is it not able to pick up the other workbook?

Comment: I don't know, you never replied when I asked *is the downloaded workbook simply open in "protected mode" in the same instance?*

Comment: I am using the Bloomberg add In. It seems like other people have had the same problem but I haven't seen any answers online yet. https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/864240-visual-basic-applications-bloomberg-issue.html

Answer (score 0):

Different instances of Excel can't communicate with each other, but several workbooks open in the same instance can easily 'talk' to each other.

If you select several Excel files and hit the Enter key, they are all running in the same instance.  If that describes your scenario, you can easily list all Workbooks, and all sheets as well, by running the code below.

```
Sub ListWorkbooks()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next

    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Out put to (single cell)", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Set WorkRng = WorkRng.Range("A1")
    xNum1 = Application.Workbooks.Count
    For i = 1 To xNum1
        xNum2 = Application.Workbooks(i).Sheets.Count
        WorkRng.Offset(i - 1, 0).Value = Application.Workbooks(i).Name
        For j = 1 To xNum2
            WorkRng.Offset(i - 1, j).Value = Application.Workbooks(i).Sheets(j).Name
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```